# Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect,

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

```
 useEffect(() => { 
      const onChildAdd = database().ref('/User/' + user.uid ).on('value', snapshot => {
    setComplete(snapshot.val().Complete);
    setUserProfile(snapshot.val().User);  
    setStartYear(snapshot.val().StartYear);
     setDisplayName(snapshot.val().displayName);
    setDisplayPicture(snapshot.val().photoURL);
    // ...
    });
    
    
    return () =>
   database().ref('/User/' + user.uid  )
        .off('value', onChildAdd);


    }, [user.uid])
```

**This is how each of them is used**

```
<Text>My name is {displayName}</Text>
```

**Error**
*Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.*

Comment: does `setUserProfile(snapshot.val().User); ` update `user`? you have a dependency only `user.id` which I assume is a string. it seems that for every call on database you get a different `user.uid` which that's the reason you get that error

Comment: As @buzatto pointed out, you've caused an infinite loop where each time the `useEffect` handler is added, the user profile is updated, which resets your `useEffect` handler and updates the profile again. You should swap out `[user.uid]` for `[activeUserId]` or `[currentUserId]` and ensure that you don't set it from inside your `useEffect` handler. Then when you want to sync a another user's data, just change `activeUserId`/`currentUserId` and it will correctly fetch the new data.

Comment: So meaning that ```user``` and ```User``` are the same thing?

Comment: ```user.uid``` is from the authentication document that is called into this document while ```User``` is just read from the document

Comment: When I deleted ```SetUserProfile(snapshot.val().User``` , the error persisted

Comment: I knew this was the useEffect that caused it because when I deleted it, that error didn't show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using default value in code above this snippet?

if you do

```
const myComponent (props)=>{
    const {user = {}, stuff } = props; 

    {/* code here that accesses 'user' object inside hooks */}

    return <h1>Hi></h1>

}
```

A new object may be created for the 'user' variable on every render!
Either use defaultprops or move the empty object creation out of the render loop

```
const empty = {};

const myComponent (props)=>{
    const {user = empty, stuff } = props; 

    {/* code here that accesses 'user' object inside hooks */}

    return <h1>Hi></h1>

}
```